# Wiring for an IsEasy cooktop

Tags: electrical, wiring

wiring picture from an IsEasy cooktop.  The picture shows 3 wires marked 240v each going into the unit with a common and a ground.  Does this mean I would connect both sides of the 240 wiring coming into the wall (2 hot out of phase 120) to the three wires into the unit?
I assume this is a European wiring pattern.  Just want to be sure before I order the product.

Comment: What picture? perhaps you could consider showing it.

Comment: 3 hots implies 3-phase power to me. Not compatible with North America dual-leg 240/120V.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide more detail. There are a lot of missing details that are necessary to get you a good (i.e. _safe_) answer.

Comment: **It's only sold on eBay** and Amazon Marketplace (which is eBay)  Sounds like your thrifty gene has taken over from your safety gene.  This thing will burn your house down, and then, fire insurance won't pay.

Comment: Sounds like 3-phase - have you got 3 phase power available?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - But it IsEasy.